# Fatal error: Class 'MySQLi' not found on windows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I installed apache and php and have it up and running (I can access the php.ini via localhost). I'm trying to access mysqli code and cannot find it. The following script indicates mysqli doesn't exist.

```
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    echo 'We don\'t have mysqli!!!';
} else {
    echo 'Phew we have it!';
}
```

I already modified the php.ini file to uncomment extension=php_mysqli.dll as well as the windows extension_dir (extension_dir = "ext")

php is located in c:/php

Comment: did you restart everything after making the system file change?

Comment: ...if not; do and try it again. If it works, you can delete the question.

Comment: Yes I restarted my computer as well as the apache server

Comment: I just tried this on mine and it worked fine.

Comment: Is `php_mysqli.dll` in the ext/ dir?

Comment: yes I'm looking at it right now c:/php/ext/php_mysqli.dll

Comment: Didn't realize the extension_dir = "ext" needed to be changed to "c:/php/ext"

Answer (score 8):

I had to change the extension_dir = "ext" to "c:/php/ext"

Comment: FYI: `extension_dir` is located in "ini" files. In particular, here are instructions for Windows OS: https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php